# How to adjust svg in the center of square with the ability to dynamically adjust to screen

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I'm looking for a way to to place SVG icon in the center of square div and adapt it over the length(width) and height of dynamic changing c column.
I want to achieve something like that [here](http://samherbert.net/svg-loaders/), in how it looks.

As the width and the height dynamicly changes `line-height` not suitable as in the example.
I am looking for way to center it vertical and horizontal in the center of the div without line-height.

It's okay if flex will be involved.

I thought to add to each square width 15% but the problem that the height is not adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if Iunderstanding correct but maybe like this,
and if you don't want it to "snap down a line" when re scaling you could delete the min width and min height.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    margin 0;
    padding 0;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.box {
    width:20%;
    height:20vw;
    min-width:100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin:1%;
    background:DodgerBlue ;
    float:left;
    background-image: url("http://www.youtube.com/yt/brand/media/image/YouTube-icon-dark.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fxoL2wzy/)**

Answer (score 1):

Basing on Patrik Fröhler answer I had a few problems with the height :(
To correct this helped usage of "calc" here is my final code, may be will help someone.

```
#wrapper {
 width:70%;
}

.box {
 width:20%;
 padding-bottom: calc(20% * 4 / 4);
 margin:1%;
 background:DodgerBlue ;
 float:left;
 background-image: url("https://cipherpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/box-512.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:70%;
 background-position: center center;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fxoL2wzy/18/)